# SwiftUI - Style Picker like in form

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form, swiftui-picker

How can I style a picker to make it look like in form, but without it being nested in it?
In form picker looks like a navigation link which takes you to a separate screen where you can pick one option. I want such behaviour in list, but without changing list style to InsetGroupedListStyle or GroupedListStyle.

[Now my picker looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctq8Z.jpg):

But I want it to look [somehow like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NmhK.jpg) (I added GroupedListStyle for an example), but with the list style from previous screenshot